# How to convert rgb to hexadecimal using GTK?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

How to convert rgb to hexadecimal using GTK?

I can convert from hex to rgb using `gdk_rgba_parse (GdkRGBA *rgba, const gchar *spec);`, but not the reverse.

Comment: I don't think GTK+ has a dedicated function to do this. You can do it easily, though: scale your components to 0..255 if necessary and use `g_strdup_printf()` to dynamically format the resultant string using the `%02X` format. You can do this by hand into a `char[8]` if you so choose as well. `GdkRGBA` uses floating-point components in the range [0,1]; to turn this into 0..255 simply multiply by 255 and truncate to an integer.

Comment: @andlabs Rather than 255.0, what if the scaling was `255.999...`?  This would allow a value just under 1.0 to map to 255.  IOWs, with `*255`, [0.0000...0.0039] maps to 0. [0.0040...0.0078] maps to 1, ... [0.9961...0.9999] maps to 254, but only [1.000] maps to 255.  With `*255.999...`, the mappings are nearly equally divided.  Or maybe `(int) (rgba.red*255 + 0.5/255)` to get a _rounded_ color?

Comment: @chux interesting; I'll have to think about this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this manually:

```
sprintf(spec, "#%02X%02X%02X", (int)(rgba.red*255), (int)(rgba.green*255), (int)(rgba.blue*255));
```

Be sure to provide a buffer large enough to hold the string or use g_strdup_printf instead.

Comment: You will need to cast those multiplications to `unsigned int` in order to use them with `%X`.

Comment: Thanks! Note: You forgot a comma.

Comment: Correct. I fixed that.